# rails 4 form_tag to return pdf format (prawn)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, pdf, prawn

I would like to have a form_tag which returns a pdf.

This is the form_tag in my view:

```
<%= form_tag do_some_things_path, method: :get do %>

  <strong>Start date</strong>
  <%= text_field_tag 'start_date', nil, id: 'start_date' %>

  <%= submit_tag 'Do the things' %>

<% end %>
```

This is the action in my controller:

```
def do_some_things
  @start_date = params[:start_date].to_date
  @stuff = "123"
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { render :something }
    format.pdf do
      pdf = SomeThingsPdf.new(@stuff)
      send_data pdf.render, filename: Time.zone.today,
                            type: "application/pdf",
                            disposition: "inline"
    end
  end
end
```

The entering a date and clicking on the button returns a beautiful html document.  But that isn't what I want - I wanted a PDF!  I have tried variations of `format: :pdf` in the header (before `method: :get`) and near the `submit` tag, but nothing works.  Can someone please point me in the right direction?  I really appreciate your help, SO community!

Comment: Try `do_some_things_path(format: :pdf)`. I can't tell whether that can help, it's a guess, but it's got a reason behind it.

Comment: thanks D-side! that worked!  It seems that do_some_things_path(format: :pdf) **does** work, but do_some_things_path, format: :pdf **does not**

Comment: D-side I would love to "accept" your answer as correct, but it is a comment not an answer... if you shift it, I will accept it :)

Comment: Done. I wasn't really sure it would help, so I didn't post it as an answer.

Answer (score 8):

Just add a hidden field like this:

`<%= hidden_field_tag :format, :pdf %>`

It works!

Answer (score 1):

`form_tag`, in essence, only needs a correct path to submit the form to.

Since most of the Rails routes end in `.:format`, you can just add this parameter to a route helper call. Like:

```
…_path(format: :pdf)
```

Answer (score 0):

recently I've built a similar web page to the one you want using the [wicked_pdf gem](https://github.com/mileszs/wicked_pdf). It is a gem that renders html to pdf easily.
Your controller methods could then respond as pdf, you could mimic the html of the page you want to render but with some wicked_pdf notations on it. They have a pretty clear tutorial.

Comment: And yet it doesn't explain what's wrong in the code above. So I believe you answered a different question.

Comment: I've pointed this solution because is much simpler than using prawn, it will be faster to implement with wicked_pdf gem.

Comment: Thanks for the information Diogo, but I already have quite a large Rails project where I use Prawn in quite a large number of cases.  I would prefer to stick with Prawn because of that reason.